# StructLayout limitation in F# Interactive?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I noticed that if I define a struct with StructLayout.Sequential, like so:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)>]
type SomeType =
 val mutable Field1: uint32
 val mutable Field2: uint32
```

This compiles and works fine in a real program, but FSI gives error `error FS0193: internal error: Could not load type 'SomeType' from assembly 'FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because field 'Field1' was not given an explicit offset.`

Is this a bug or limitation of FSI? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I am reproducing this behavior with Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.30110.0

Comment: [You should file this as a bug with Microsoft.](http://fslang.uservoice.com/)

Comment: Not sure this belongs on F# language design though?

Comment: Just for completness: with Pack=0 it works, any other value causes the error to be thrown.

Comment: ref to bug https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/342

Answer (score 5):

Workaround (the error has a hint):

```
[<Struct;StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type SomeType =
    [<FieldOffset(0)>]
    val mutable Field1: uint32
    [<FieldOffset(4)>]
    val mutable Field2: uint32
```